# overlaid scatter plot where each data point has a different color and shape

Tags: r, graph

I want to visualize a data transformation. My data is in 2 dimensions and the transformation is in 3 dimensions. I am interested in seeing how each data point is transformed in the higher dimensions. So overlaid two scatter plots using scatterplot3d package. The data which is in 2 dimensions has third coordinate assigned as 0 for plotting purposes. To keep track of each datapoint, I want to assign a unique color and shape in 2D and the transformed data value will have same color and shape in 3D. I was able to assign unique color but not shape since shapes are limited(my n=50). Any idea to make this visualization better ? Here is my reproducible example.

```
install.packages("scatterplot3d")
library(scatterplot3d)
set.seed(20)
# example 
M<-cbind(a=runif(50),b=runif(50),c=rep(0,n))
N<-cbind(d=rnorm(50),e=rnorm(50),f=rnorm(50))
s3d<-scatterplot3d(N[,1],N[,2],N[,3],color=rainbow(n),type="p",pch=0
,xlab="x",ylab="y ",zlab="z")
    s3d$points3d(M[,1],M[,2],M[,3],col=rainbow(n),type="p",pch=15)
```

[image]

Comment: Ehrm, what do you mean by "better"? Do you want still  to have different shapes or are you asking for a more generic approach? :)

Comment: Yes. Use shapes along with colors or some other approach say assin id to each data point and use that instead of shape.

Comment: Well If your data is more than say 50-100 points, you won't be able to perceive much by colouring all points. An idea could be to colour only the "3d outlier points", so that you can follow them.